# Typography for label

Tags: wpf, label

Cant Add Typography to my label font in WPF. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Any more additional information? E.g. your code.

Answer (score 1):

Well setting the Font works for me, so you might need to say more about what your require.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label FontFamily="Lucida Grande" 
                   FontSize="13" 
                   FontStyle="Italic">Typography words</Label>
    <Label>Normal words</Label>
</StackPanel>
```